# How do I write the following condition in a single Python if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have three disjoint lists containing integers: `list_a` , `list_b`  and `list_c` . I want to check if any pair of elements, one in `list_a`  and one in `list_b`  exists, such that the `list_a`  element is smaller than the `list_b`  element, and there is no element in `list_c`  that lies between the `list_a`  element and `list_b`  element.

For an example:

```
list_a = [0, 1, 4, 5, 8]
list_b = [3, 7]
list_c = [2, 6, 9]
```

We see that 1 < 3, but 2 lies between 1 and 3. Similarly 5 < 7, but 6 lies between 5 and 7.

Therefore, the condition should result as false with these three lists.

However, if we had the following three lists:

```
list_a = [0, 1, 4, 5, 8]
list_b = [3, 7]
list_c = [6, 9]
```

the condition should hold true, because 1 < 3, and there is no element in `list_c` that lies between 1 and 3.

I am unable to think of a way to check for this condition without using for/while loops, which I want to avoid. How can I check for this condition in a concise single-line statement?

Thank you.

Comment: I dont understand the expected output

Comment: and you don't really know what are `any()` and `all()`, those functions return True or False

Comment: Yes, I realised that now. I apologise.

Comment: so please fix your question

Answer (score 0):

The following is a concise way but I am not sure if it is readable enough. However, loop is kind of inevitable here:

```
import itertools
if( any( a<b and not any( (a<x and x<b) for x in list_c) for a,b in itertools.product(list_a, list_b)) ):
```

Comment: This seems to be working. A more readable way of writing it would be


`any(a < b and not any((a < x < b) for x in list_c) for (a, b) in itertools.product(list_a, list_b))`

Thank you.

Comment: ya sure, my bad